# Questões sobre teoria de computação e outros temas mais acadêmicos

Tags: debate, big-7, escopo-do-site

Com a fragmentação dos sites em inglês, temos uma gama de sites intersectantes, como SO, cstheory.SE, cs.SE, crypto.SE e possivelmente outros.

Imagino que o SOpt esteja seguindo um modelo de "árvore-B" quanto aos tópicos, acumulando-os todos em um nó até que o site fique grande e, então, quebrando-o em subtópicos e movendo as perguntas para os sites relevantes.

Segundo este modelo, me parece razoável agregar estudantes e pesquisadores de Computação no SOpt também. O que vocês acham?

Comment: A resposta a esta pergunta tem a ver com esta: http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/112/stack-overflow-em-portugues-e-somente-o-stackoverflow-em-portugues-ou-e-mais-abr

Comment: @Sergio valeu! A pergunta que vc citou parece duplicada [desta](http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/1/aqui-no-o-stackoverflow-com?rq=1), mas com ponto de vista diferente nas respostas. Parece que a resposta oficial é que o SOpt é mais abrangente e não deve ter as mesmas regras estritas do SO em inglês, mas isso funciona mais como uma "constituição", com os casos específicos deixados para regulamentação própria. Acho importante, assim, levantar se o caso acadêmico entra no "abrangente" ou não. Eu voto que sim.

Comment: Não sei se o SO original foi mais abrangente no principio. Acho que foi "especializado" desde o princípio e criou "inveja boa" em outras àreas levando à criação de outros sites mais específicos. Alguém por aqui sabe como foram os primeiros dias do SOen ?

Comment: Sou 100% a favor!

Comment: O SO nasceu envolvendo mais ou menos tudo que envolvia desenvolvimento, um pouco mais estrito do que deveremos fazer aqui, porém mais abrangente do que é hoje.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Acredito que sim, o SO historicamente agregou toda esta comunidade que depois foi sendo redistribuída. Mas perceba que a redistribuição foi realizada de acordo com as regras de cada comunidade.

Nesta thread ([Where on SE to discuss computer science](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80023/where-on-se-to-discuss-computer-science)) uma discussão bem interessante acontece sobre onde colocar as perguntas de CS. Ela inclui dois pontos que achei interessantíssimos: (1) a rejeição da comunidade "cstheory" de certas perguntas de CS e (2) a utilização de estatísticas de "fechamento" de perguntas em uma determinada comunidade para decidir se as mesmas devem ter seu próprio lugar.

Esta outra ([Programmers is about to go live, which questions should we migrate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71731/programmers-is-about-to-go-live-which-questions-should-we-migrate)) apesar de não falar sobre CS mostra como foram definidas as regras de migração para perguntas do SO para o Programmers. Sendo assim, mais um exemplo de que as coisas foram sendo separadas quando necessárias.

Portanto, volto a apontar para a pergunta "Aqui não é SO.com", principalmente porque estamos num momento muito embrionário para decidirmos o que sai!

Abraços.