# Usar o SOPT para tirar dúvidas em cursos do Coursera?

Tags: debate

Estou começando um grupo de estudos para fazer o curso de [Criptografia I do Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/course/crypto), e gostaria da opinião da comunidade/moderadores sobre a viabilidade de usar o SOPT (sob a tag criptografia, provavelmente) como ponto de encontro para dúvidas que surgirem, de forma a contribuir conteúdo de qualidade à comunidade.

Como o objetivo do site é ser uma referência útil a *qualquer* programador, não apenas aos que estejam fazendo o curso, naturalmente as perguntas teriam de ser formuladas de maneira **livre de contexto**.

Por exemplo: em vez de perguntar "como se demonstra a afirmação no slide X", a pessoa poderia perguntar "Por que um *stream cypher* ser demonstravelmente seguro implica em P != NP?"

Sugeri o uso do SOPT para este fim a professores de criptografia da Unicamp, que gostaram da ideia e se dispuseram a contribuir. Acho que a comunidade só tem a ganhar, já que é um assunto com tão pouco material disponível em português e que certamente só deve aumentar em relevância daqui em diante. Agradeço desde já o feedback.

Perguntas relacionadas:

[Aqui NÃO É o stackoverflow.com](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1/aqui-no-o-stackoverflow-com)

[Questões sobre teoria de computação e outros temas mais acadêmicos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/117/questoes-sobre-teoria-de-computacao-e-outros-temas-mais-academicos)

Comment: Tranquilo. Isso enriqueceria muito o SOPT. Acho que é bastante alinhado com o propósito do site.

Comment: Me parece muito interessante e viável. Aliás, você sabe se esse curso é muito básico? Estou pensando em fazer.

Comment: Ele não se aprofunda muito, mas dá um panorama bem legal. Vale a pena. Já teve o Cryptography II também que provavelmente vão repetir.

Comment: Com ctz suas perguntas serão muito bem vindas aqui, e pelo que voce escreveu dá pra ver que você ja sabe como utilizar o site, fazendo perguntas que sejam respondíveis por qualquer pessoa que entenda do assunto e que não necessariamente faz o curso.

Comment: Acredito que entre você e alguém que faz um faculdade/curso e faz perguntas por aqui não existem diferenças. Dúvida é duvida. Só não acho interessante em criar tags específicas nem nada do tipo, minha opnião, claro.